# Randomly selected two integers are relatively prime

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, number-theory

> The probability that two integers $m$ and $n$  picked at random are relatively prime is  $6/\pi^2$

There is a simple code to check it

```
n = 10^6;

Count[GCD @@@ RandomInteger[{1, n}, {n, 2}], 1]/n // N
```

> $0.607687$

```
N[6/Pi^2]
```

> $0.607927$

How can I use `CoprimeQ` function?

I want to do something like this

```
 n = 10^6;

Select[RandomInteger[{1, n}, {n, 2}], CoprimeQ]
```

or

```
CoprimeQ[#1, #2] &[RandomInteger[{1, n}, {n, 2}]]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `Select[RandomInteger[{1, n}, {n, 2}], Apply[CoprimeQ]]`

Comment: `Count[GCD @@@ RandomInteger[{1, n}, {n, 2}], 1]/n // N` is 4 time faster than  `Length@Select[RandomInteger[{1, n}, {n, 2}], Apply[CoprimeQ]]/n // N`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZBhSi_PwHU